# Bold, Italic links do not show in link colour on old mobile site

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, mobile-site

The '***HERE***' in the screenshot below is a link, although when viewing the answer through the mobile site, it doesn't have the blue link colour.

The example answer is [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/34810/28182)

Here is the link when viewing on mobile:
[image: mobile screenshot of a link without link style]

Here it is viewed in 'desktop mode' on mobile:
[image: desktop mode]

And on desktop proper:
[image: on a PC]

#### Reproduced on:

- HTC One M8 (Android 5.0.2, Software Number 4.24.709.2)

  - Google Chrome for Android (v44.0.2403.133)
  - Firefox for Android (v40.0)
  - Dolphin Browser (v11.4.17)
  - Stock HTC browser (v7.1.2517332452)
- Samsung Galaxy S6 EDGE

  - Chrome 44.0.2403.133
  - Stock Browser

Comment: does it still work as a link? do external links work in the mobile version?

Comment: @Aequitas - yes and yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

The mobile site design has been replaced with a [responsive version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367609/179041), thus this bug is no longer reproducible